# Inputstream is null, while loading a file from a file path in windows service

Tags: java, windows-services, classpath, yajsw

Im trying to read a file from a path.
This is my sample code;

```
String path = "repository"+ File.separator +"resources"+ File.separator +"api_templates";

        String fileName = path + TEMPLATE_FILE_PREFIX + type + ".xml";
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
           log.info("##############File path#############"+fileName);
            in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

Here i get inputstream as null. I suspect the system could not load the file. But when i print my filepath, it correctly prints my file path.

This problem occurs only when i try to run my server as windows service, using "yajsw".

What might be the issue?

Edit:

My Sample wrapper-conf file;

```
#********************************************************************
 # working directory
 #********************************************************************
```

wrapper.working.dir=${my_home}

```
 ............

 wrapper.java.additional.2 = -Xms256m 
 wrapper.java.additional.3 = -Xmx1024m 
 wrapper.java.additional.4 = -XX:MaxPermSize=256m 
 wrapper.java.additional.5 = -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError 
 wrapper.java.additional.6 = -XX:HeapDumpPath=${my_home}\\repository\\logs\\heap-dump.hprof  
 wrapper.java.additional.7 = -Djava.endorsed.dirs=${my_home}\\lib\\endorsed;${java_home}\\jre\\lib\\endorsed
```

Comment: It might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464291/how-to-really-read-text-file-from-classpath-in-java

Comment: @Muthu Thanks, but those suggestion did not work for me. I always pass "absolute" path in my code. (Please check my above code segment).When i run this as a normal java application, above works fine. Only problem is, when i run as a windows service, it could not load the file? Should i set any parameter in the wrapper.con file? I have set the working.directory parameter and the classpaths are correctly. So, my application is started as a windows service successfully, but when i try to laod the files, system could not. Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a classpath issue between resources and files. We can not use classloaders to access files. For that we need to use File, filereader, file input stream. After changing like this everything works fine;

> InputStream in = new FileInputStream(filePath);